# Different directory size between GUI and Command Line

Tags: du, nautilus

I got this weird size problem using Gnome:
the size of Desktop directory is: 541.2 GB
(right click properties)

however when I run this command on a shell I get different size:

```
du -sh Desktop/
1.1T Desktop/
```

any ideas why "du" gives double the size? of a Gnome nautilus.

Comment: Is there still a discrepency if you choose `View >> Show Hidden Files` before doing the sizing in Nautilus?

Comment: There might be a difference between actual file size and size taken on drive by this file. See: http://www.howtogeek.com/180369/why-is-there-a-big-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk/

Comment: I am using gpfs filesystem

Comment: Is this true of all directories or just `Desktop`? Do you have any non-gpfs filesystems you can try this on?

Comment: This is on all directories. Is it because of mirroring of the home directories? But still doesn't make sense; du -sh and ls -lh always give double the size of nautilus...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get no differences using

```
du -sh folder/ --apparent-size
```